# which event of form1 is fired when form2 closes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have two forms in my project

When I click on a button on Form1, Form2 opens.

I have some textboxes on form2.

When I write some text in that textboxes I have a button Save.

By Clicking that Save Button the data is saved to database and form2 closes. So form1 is shown.

I have a datagridview in form1. It has data from the table in which I save data from form2.

Now the problem is that When I click on save button on form2 the datagridview in form1 does not have the last record that was added.

This is very expected behavior because I fill data in datagridview in form1.Load event.

So which event should I use so that data in DataGridView is refreshed?

I have tried `paint event of form1` but that does not work.

I have tried `form1.refresh()` in `form2.Closing` event.

I have also tried `gotFocus event of form1` but it crashes the program unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest if possible opening the form using `form2.ShowDialog` as this is a blocking call rather than `form2.Show`.

When form 2 closes then the code will continue on to the following line after `ShowDialog` call allowing you to refresh thew list.

The alternative is to create your own event:

1) Define a new event in form2 `Public Event EventName()`
2) Use `AddHandler form2Instance.EventName, AddressOf HandlerFunctionName` in form 1 to hook into the event
3) After save code in form2 use `RaiseEvent EventName` that will trigger the code

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I have the solution. I was not hiding my form1 when I showed form2. I made form1.visible = False in button's event and I got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

you could call a refresh method on your Form1 if you need to refresh the data to your DataGridView. You could call the same method on your Form1 Load to populate the data.

If for example you had a method called RefreshData() you could do this on closing Form2

```
Dim frm1 = CType(Form1, Application.OpenForms("Form1"))
frm1.RefreshData()
```

What is the underlying datasource to your DataGridView? There may be a better option but more info would be needed to know.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I have the solution. I was not hiding my form1 when I showed form2. I made form1.visible = False in button's event and I got it to work.